How to move fields out from a struct when parent struct itself has already moved, possible refactor?
I'm currently learning Rust and have read the handbook so I have a basic understanding of borrows & ownership. However when it comes to concurrency and struct fields I'm struggling to implement the following simple bi-directional async byte reader/writer.
Is there some way to access the server.device after when the server_fut has moved server into the async function? I'm expecting some sort of Mutex too but unsure whether the Mutex should be on the Server or Device.
Perhaps this is an A/B problem as the current structure might need to be refactored.
use std::num::NonZero;
use swimos_byte_channel::{self, ByteReader, ByteWriter};
use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};

struct Server {
    device: Device,
}

impl Server {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Server {
            device: Device::new(4096),
        }
    }

    async fn run(&mut self) {
        loop {
            let mut buf = [0; 4096];
            let size = self.device.in_reader.read(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
            let buf_vec = buf[..size].to_vec();

            let mut msg = String::from_utf8(buf_vec).unwrap();
            msg.push_str(" - processed!");

            self.device.out_writer.write(msg.as_bytes()).await.unwrap();
        }
    }
}

struct Device {
    in_writer: ByteWriter,
    in_reader: ByteReader,
    out_writer: ByteWriter,
    out_reader: ByteReader,
}

impl Device {
    fn new(size: usize) -> Device {
        let (in_writer, in_reader) = swimos_byte_channel::byte_channel(NonZero::new(size).unwrap());
        let (out_writer, out_reader) = swimos_byte_channel::byte_channel(NonZero::new(size).unwrap());
        Device {
            in_writer,
            in_reader,
            out_writer,
            out_reader,
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut server = Server::new();

    let server_fut = async move {
        server.run().await;
    };
    let server_handle = tokio::spawn(server_fut);

    let mut in_writer = server.device.in_writer; // ! Cannot be accessed due to existing move
    let mut out_reader = server.device.out_reader; // ! Cannot be access due to existing move

    let in_write_fut = async move {
        loop {
            tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
            
            let data = b"Hello World".to_vec();
            in_writer.write(&data).await.unwrap();
        }
    };

    let out_read_fut = async move {
        loop {
            tokio::time::sleep(tokio::time::Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
            
            let mut buf = [0; 1000];
            let size = out_reader.read(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
            println!("Read: {:?}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&buf[..size]));
        }
    };
    
    let write_fut_handle = tokio::spawn(in_write_fut);
    let read_fut_handle = tokio::spawn(out_read_fut);

    tokio::try_join!(server_handle, write_fut_handle, read_fut_handle);

}


If your server .run() only needs in_reader and out_writer while the other tasks only need in_writer and out_reader, then you should split up your Device.

I have tried that, but the problem is both AsyncRead and AsyncWrite requires &mut self, and both threads cannot get a mutable ref to the parent Struct Server itself

You should split up your Device so that your Server doesn't own all the readers and writers (only the two it needs) so the ones not used by the server can be given to your tasks.

I see, so create the channel (reader/writer pair) outside of the server, then only pass in the needed endpoints (in_read and out_write)?

tokio has io::split().

Split the struct Device
just as @kmdreko pointed out, if the device struct doesn't need the in_writer and out_reader, you should extract it
use std::num::NonZero;
use swimos_byte_channel::{self, ByteReader, ByteWriter};
use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};

struct Server {
    device: Device,
}

impl Server {
    fn new() -> (Self, ByteWriter, ByteReader) {
        let size = 4096;
        let (in_writer, in_reader) = swimos_byte_channel::byte_channel(NonZero::new(size).unwrap());
        let (out_writer, out_reader) = swimos_byte_channel::byte_channel(NonZero::new(size).unwrap());
        let device = Device::new(in_reader, out_writer);
        (Server { device }, in_writer, out_reader)
    }

    async fn run(&mut self) { /* ... */ }
}

struct Device {
    in_reader: ByteReader,
    out_writer: ByteWriter,
}

impl Device {
    fn new(in_reader: ByteReader, out_writer: ByteWriter) -> Device {
        Device {
            in_reader,
            out_writer,
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (mut server, mut in_writer, mut out_reader) = Server::new();
    /* ... */
}

Take
You can use Option<_> to hold the value temporarily, and use take() to take the value out of the struct when needed.
use std::num::NonZero;
use swimos_byte_channel::{self, ByteReader, ByteWriter};
use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};

struct Server {
    device: Device,
}

impl Server {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Server {
            device: Device::new(4096),
        }
    }
    async fn run(&mut self) { /* ... */ }
}

struct Device {
    in_writer: Option<ByteWriter>,
    in_reader: ByteReader,
    out_writer: ByteWriter,
    out_reader: Option<ByteReader>,
}

impl Device {
    fn new(size: usize) -> Device {
        let (in_writer, in_reader) = swimos_byte_channel::byte_channel(NonZero::new(size).unwrap());
        let (out_writer, out_reader) = swimos_byte_channel::byte_channel(NonZero::new(size).unwrap());
        let in_writer = Some(in_writer);
        let out_reader = Some(out_reader);
        Device {
            in_writer,
            in_reader,
            out_writer,
            out_reader,
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut server = Server::new();
    let mut in_writer = server.device.in_writer.take().unwrap();
    let mut out_reader = server.device.out_reader.take().unwrap();
    /* ... */
}

Maybe Mutex
if your Device struct also need access to in_writer and out_reader, you probably will need to use Mutex<_>

Thanks I managed to get it working by not having Device hold the readers and writers it doesn't need access to.
